# Does the Doctor really have to "pay back" the vision he borrowed?

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode Extremis, the Doctor "borrows" sight from his future self so that he can see temporarily. But we later find out

> that the Doctor is part of a simulated world, and is not the real Doctor

Clearly the answer to this question might depend on what happens in the next episode, but does this mean that there is no real need for this vision to be "paid back" like it was implied when he "borrowed" it?

on a side note (not part of the actual question)

> how did a race so terrible at simulating random numbers manage to construct a hyper-realistic world with apparently conscious agents?

Comment: I reckon they got lazy - used [PRNG's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) and just gave everyone the same seed state :)

Comment: Depends how good the simulation is. Maybe it's so good that the Gallifreyan reading aid really borrowed some eyesight time from the real Doctor's future selves. Since there's a good chance we'll never hear about this ever again, we'll probably never know.

Answer (score 6):

We don't know what the price of the eyesight was. Neither did the Doctor.

> "Maybe all my future regenerations will be blind. Maybe I can't regenerate."

I would argue that the price paid was death. For as we saw, about 1-2 hours later (in-universe time), he presumably died (via pixelating disintegration like Bill and Nardole) at the hands of The Monks. So in a way, he was correct that he would not be able to regenerate again.